# How do I convert a created a path to a selection?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, selections

I drew a path around an element that I plan to create a new layer from. I started by outlining the element with a path, I want to convert that path to a selection. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you may provide.

Answer (score 1):

With the pen tool (P) selected, Right Click -> Make Selection.

You can also go to the Paths window panel and <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd> *Click* the thumbnail to make a selection of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to by <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, creates a new layer. Hit *"Ok"*, then you can *Right Click* to select *Make Selection...* from the options.

Thats what I had to do.